# ComboBox is not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

The Binding on the ComboBox Categories is not updating when a Division is selected.
When a division is selected the ProjectCategories Property does get populated with two results, but the view does not update.

If I send ProjectCategories as a ref through to ProjectCategoriesGetByDivisionId() then the binding does update.

I don't want to pass references to my model and data classes.  How can I have the binding update without changing my model and data classes?

Here is the Divisions ComboBox that changes the value of the binding for the Categories ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Divisions" ItemsSource="{Binding Divisions}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="DivisionId">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DivisionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Divisions, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

The ComboBox that isn't updating

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Categories" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="CategoryId" />
```

The method that gets fired when the Divisions SelectedChanged event is fired.

```
private void DivisionChanged(Division d)
{
    ProjectCategories = ProjectCategory.GetByDivisionId(d.DivisionId);
}
```

ViewModel Property the ComboBox is binding to

```
public ObservableCollection<ProjectCategory> ProjectCategories
{
    get { return projectCategories; }
    set
    {
        projectCategories = value;

        if (base.PropertyChangedHandler != null)
            base.PropertyChangedHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProjectCategories"));
    }
}
```

Model Method that is called

```
public static ObservableCollection<ProjectCategory> GetByDivisionId(int divisionId)
{
    return ProjectData.ProjectCategoriesGetByDivisionId(divisionId);
}
```

I think the rest is self explanitory.

```
public static ObservableCollection<ProjectCategory> ProjectCategoriesGetByDivisionId(int divisionId)
{
    ObservableCollection<ProjectCategory> projectCategory = new ObservableCollection<ProjectCategory>();
    SqlConnection conn = null;

    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TRK_ProjectCategory_GetByDivisionId", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DivisionId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = divisionId;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (sdr.Read())
            projectCategory.Add(ObjectConstructors.ProjectCategoryConstructor(sdr));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.EmailLog("MineralsData", "public static ObservableCollection<ProjectCategory> ProjectCategoriesGetByDivisionId(int divisionId)", ex.ToString(), string.Empty);
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
        conn = null;
    }

    return projectCategory;
}

public static ProjectCategory ProjectCategoryConstructor(SqlDataReader dr)
{
    ProjectCategory ec = new ProjectCategory();

    ec.CategoryId = dr["CategoryId"].SDR_GetInt();
    ec.Name = dr["Name"].SDR_GetString();
    ec.Description = dr["Description"].SDR_GetString();
    ec.LastModified = dr["LastModified"].SDR_GetDateTime();
    ec.ModifiedBy = dr["ModifiedBy"].SDR_GetString();

    return ec;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combobox is binding to a property called "categories". You don't show any other code for this property. It will only update if you call propertychanged event for categories. Did you mean to bind to "ProjectCategories"?

Comment: Thank you, that looks like it is the problem I looked at that for a long time and never saw it...  I'll test it tomorrow and mark you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lee said, your xmal is binding to an object called `Categories`, but in viewmodel you have `ProjectCategories`, change category combobox to

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Categories" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectCategories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="CategoryId" />
```

You don't need call propertychanged event since you are already raising `PropertyChangedEventHandler` in the setter.